# PHP - sending html mail

Tags: php

I have following PHP code to submit single input:

```
<?php

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$mailTo = 'user@gmail.com';
$mailFrom = 'user@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Call Back EN';

$body = ($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : $_POST['number'].'<br />';
$body .= 'Server IP:'.gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'<br />';
$body .= 'Czas:'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';

mail($mailTo, $subject, $number, "From: ".$mailFrom);


?>
```

But the only field I'm getting by email is number - what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you're sending only `$number`...

Comment: in the mail call, did you meant $body instead of $number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mail($mailTo, $subject, $body, "From: ".$mailFrom);
```

the `body` is act like email contents,
but you supplied it using variable `$number`,
that is why you only getting number in your email

second problem, where is the `$headers` ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

this should give you clearer picture

```
$headers .= "From: user@gmail.com";
mail($mailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting only number because you are not sending the body.
try this

```
 <?php

 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

 $mailTo = 'user@gmail.com';
 $mailFrom = 'user@gmail.com';
 $subject = 'Call Back EN';

 $body = ($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : $_POST['number'].'<br />';
  $body .= 'Server IP:'.gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'<br />';
 $body .= 'Czas:'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';

 mail($mailTo, $subject, $body, "From: ".$mailFrom);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be inserting `$body` instead of `$number`

```
mail($mailTo, $subject, $body, "From: ".$mailFrom);
```